# Method definition need to use private declaration of a class

Tags: c++, oop, syntax

I have a problem trying to create a method that its type its a private variable of her class:

*foo.h*

```
template <class T> class Foo {
  private:
    struct Node {
      T value;
      Node * following;
    }

    Node * bar( const T & elem );
}
```

*foo.cpp*

```
template <class T> Node * bar( const T & elem );
```

But Node doesn't exists in `foo.cpp`, because is a private variable of the class `Foo` `foo.h`.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In foo.cpp you are specifying the return type and name of the function incorrectly. `Node` comes from the class `Foo` so you need to qualify it with `Foo<T>::`. Same goes with the member function `bar`:

```
template <class T>
typename Foo<T>::Node* Foo<T>::bar( const T & elem );
//       ^^^^^^^^      ^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: error: invalid use of template-name ‘Foo’ without an argument list

Comment: @TomiSebastiánJuárez Oops. You also need the template argument: `Foo<T>::`

Comment: Oh, but now... error: need ‘typename’ before ‘Foo<T>::Node’ because ‘Foo<T>’ is a dependent scope

Comment: @TomiSebastiánJuárez Yes, you also need `typename` before the return type. Sorry 'bout that. :)